# Convert MMMM, dd yyyy date to UTC date

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, format

I have date like this: December, 08 2020

and I need to convert it in format similar to this: 2020-02-03T09:00:00

(time part must be there but it can be whatever, time is not relevant)

Comment: Welcome, this is not how StackOverflow works. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Dates typically don't have an associated timezone, they're usually treated as local so 8 Dec 2020 is the same date everywhere. Adding a timezone means it may be 7 Dec 2020 in about half the world.

Answer (score -1):

Welcome to SO.

you can simply use

```js
console.log(new Date('December, 08 2020 00:00:00 GMT').toISOString())
```

Appending the string ' 00:00:00 GMT' with help you in getting consistent result across timezones.

Comment: also gives `2020-12-07T23:00:00.000Z` for me in central europe

Comment: @Argee We can simply append 00:00:00 GMT string to make sure it doesn't change according to timezone

Comment: See [*Why does Date.parse give incorrect results?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587345/why-does-date-parse-give-incorrect-results)

Comment: interpreting the string with an own implementation seems to be the way to go then?

Comment: @Argee, Sorry you're saying the day change but output is  2020-12-08T00:00:00.000Z. Where is the day change in my proposed solution after edit?

Comment: there is not any... in the pre-edit version there was, like you said yourself :D